# Decoding Mp3 file in java

Tags: java, mp3

I am trying to design Shazam like app for Desktop in java.I took input from Microphone having format 
**sample rate=44100,sample size in bits=16,Channels=1,signed=true and bigendian=true.** and perform FFT.Similarly for creating Database of MP3 songs i am **decoding MP3 file in the same format as input from microphone**.
and this process is giving me too much samples and that slows FFT process of mp3 files.

So my doubt is that how i can handle this problem.